# Remove/Add disable to text box on select box change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a select box and a text input box, what i want is when the select box is not selected on an actual option with a value then the text input to be disabled, but when the select box select an option then for the disabled to be removed from the text box. For some reason it is not removing the disabled from the textbox on select of option.

Here is the javascript of the on change for the select

```
$('#pro_content_select_country').on('change', function() {

  var  optionValue = $(this).val();
    if(optionValue !== NULL){           
    $('#pro_content_input_local').removeAttr('disabled');          
     }else{
     $('#pro_content_input_local').attr('disabled','disabled'); 
    }  

});
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening, also i am disabling the text box on window load as default and running this same script on window load as well to remove it if necessary.

Thanks

Comment: `NULL` is not a keyword in JavaScript, but `null` is.

Comment: Try changing `if(optionValue !== NULL)` for `if(optionValue !== "")`. Also, if you're using a jquery > 1.6, maybe you'll want to use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

Comment: @EthanBrown is correct: http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/dEZ7N/

Comment: Thankyou that change worked great, a bit silly really i missed that, just out of interest what is the difference between `.prop()` and `.attr()`?

Comment: The docs would explain better than me :P http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: Hi, i was just testing the above code again and for some reason if you select and option with no value it doesn't re disable the text input, any reason why?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#pro_content_select_country').on('change', function() {
    if($(this).val()){           
        $('#pro_content_input_local').removeAttr('disabled');          
    }else{
        $('#pro_content_input_local').attr('disabled','disabled'); 
    }  
});
```